# How do I install service stack 4 side-by-side with asp.net MVC 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, routes, localhost, servicestack

I've gone through all of the steps in the servicestack documentation and followed the advice of a similar post here on Stack Overflow, but whenever I try to access my "/api/" route, I get the following error:

```
Handler for Request not found: 


Request.HttpMethod: GET
Request.PathInfo: /api/metadata
Request.QueryString: 
Request.RawUrl: /api/api/metadata
```

Relevant sections of code:

AppHost:

```
public class HolidayEventPlannerAppHost : AppHostBase
    {
        public HolidayEventPlannerAppHost() : base("Holiday Event Planner App Host", typeof(HelloService).Assembly) { }

        public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
        {
            SetConfig(new HostConfig { HandlerFactoryPath = "api" });
        }
    }
```

Routeconfig.cs:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("api/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

In addition, when I type "localhost:port/api" in my browser's address bar, the browser gets redirected to "localhost:port/api/api/metadata" which is where I get the error message. It won't let me access "localhost:port/api/metadata".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally someone that help to eliminate the metadata completely.
You need to put:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig
    {
        HandlerFactoryPath = "api",
        MetadataRedirectPath = "/"
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using ServiceStack 3.9.70, for me in order to use ServiceStack along with MVC WebApi I had to do this:

```
SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig
    {
        ServiceStackHandlerFactoryPath = "sapi",
        MetadataRedirectPath = "sapi/metadata"
     });
```

This way I can use `api` for WebAPI and `sapi` for ServiceStack. Don't forget you need to modify the Web.Config also, [full instruction here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Run-servicestack-side-by-side-with-another-web-framework).

Answer (score 1):

There's an existing template for hosting [ServiceStack with MVC4](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Templates/tree/master/src), you'd also want to ensure that your Web.config is properly configured for ServiceStack, which you can compare with the [Mvc4 Web.Config](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Templates/blob/master/src/Host.Mvc4/Web.config).

More information about integration with MVC is [available on the wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Mvc-integration).

Comment: There seems to be an issue with the code that redirects to the metadata page.  If handlerfactorypath is "api", the default MetdataRedirectPath is determined to be "api/metadata".  The ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory attempts to create an absolute url from these two by simply joining them.

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar issues with this redirect path since using v4 of ServiceStack.

As a fix, I found that overriding the MetadataRedirectPath with the following `HostConfig` worked:

```
        SetConfig(new HostConfig
        {
            HandlerFactoryPath = "api",
            MetadataRedirectPath = "/metadata"
        });
```

I think without this config, a bug is being exposed in either how the default `MetadataRedirectPath` is determined or how the redirect url is combined with the handler factory path.